# trying to have the same label entry as the first frame to the second frame. Tkinter

Tags: python, csv, tkinter

trying to have the same label entry as the first frame to the second frame. have tried to add the second label to my function, however, it isn't registering as a label at all. trying to figure how the label entry can be saved. not sure if I should save it as a variable and then display it or just display the same label in both frames.

```
import tkinter as tk 
import tkinter.messagebox as box
import csv
from tkinter import *

window = tk.Tk()
 
window.state('zoomed')

window.title('freshta otdering system')

def show_frame(fram):
    fram.tkraise()
    

frame2 = tk.Frame(window)
frame3 = tk.Frame(window)

for frame in (frame1, frame2, frame3):
    frame.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky='nsew')


filepath = '/Users/adamcleaver/Desktop/ICT/SAT part 1 /orders.csv'
File = open(filepath)


reader = csv.reader(File)
 
Data = list (reader)
 
del(Data[0])

list_of_entries = []

for x in list(range(0,len(Data))):
    list_of_entries.append(Data[x][0])

var = StringVar(value = list_of_entries)
listbox1 = Listbox(frame2, listvariable = var)
listbox1.place(x= 10, y = 220, height = 500, width = 200)

 
def update():
    
    
    index = listbox1.curselection()[0]
    Foodlabel3.config(text = Data[index][1]) and Foodlabel2.config(text = Data[index][1])
    Drinkslabel3.config(text = Data[index][2]) and Drinkslabel2.config(text = Data[index][2])
    Pricelabel3.config(text = Data[index][3]) and Pricelabel2.config(text = Data[index][3])

    return None
    
   
#using update function within the button
button1 = tk.Button(frame2, text="Update", command=update, fg = "blue", bg='yellow')
button1.place(x=400, y=450, height = 75, width = 125)

button2 = tk.Button(frame2, text="continue", command= lambda:show_frame(frame3), fg = "blue", bg='yellow')
button2.place(x=500, y=450, height = 75, width = 125)

Foodlabel = Label(frame2, text="Food", font=('Arial',20,'bold'),bg = '#F0EAD6').place(x= 295, y= 200)
Drinkslabel = Label(frame2, text="Drinks",font=('Arial',20,'bold'),bg = '#F0EAD6').place(x= 295, y= 300)
Pricelabel = Label(frame2, text="Total price ($)",font=('Arial',20,'bold'),bg = '#F0EAD6').place(x= 275, y=400)


Foodlabel2 = Label(frame2, text="",font=('Arial',20),bg = '#F0EAD6')
Foodlabel2.place(x= 425 , y= 200)



Drinkslabel2 = Label(frame2, text="",font=('Arial',20),bg = '#F0EAD6')
Drinkslabel2.place(x= 425, y= 300)



Pricelabel2 = Label(frame2, text="",font=('Arial',20),bg = '#F0EAD6' )
Pricelabel2.place(x=425, y= 400)



#label for login 
tk.Label(frame2, text = 'Ordering' ,font=('Arial',36), fg = 'red', bg = '#F0EAD6' ).place(x=0, y=125)

tk.Label(frame2, text = 'Your order :' ,font=('Arial',36), bg = '#F0EAD6' ).place(x= 320, y=125)



#==================Frame 3 code ========================================
#label for login 
tk.Label(frame2, text = 'Ordering' ,font=('Arial',36), fg = 'red', bg = '#F0EAD6' ).place(x=0, y=125)

Foodlabel3 = Label(frame3, text="",font=('Arial',20),bg = '#F0EAD6')
Foodlabel3.place(x= 425 , y= 200)



Drinkslabel3 = Label(frame3, text="",font=('Arial',20),bg = '#F0EAD6')
Drinkslabel3.place(x= 425, y= 300)



Pricelabel3 = Label(frame3, text="",font=('Arial',20),bg = '#F0EAD6' )
Pricelabel3.place(x=425, y= 400)


frame3_btn = tk.Button(frame3, text='Enter',command=lambda:show_frame(frame1))
frame3_btn.pack(fill='x',ipady=15)

show_frame(frame1)

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not how you use `and`.  You need:

```
def update():
    index = listbox1.curselection()[0]
    Foodlabel3.config(text = Data[index][1])
    Foodlabel2.config(text = Data[index][1])
    Drinkslabel3.config(text = Data[index][2])
    Drinkslabel2.config(text = Data[index][2])
    Pricelabel3.config(text = Data[index][3])
    Pricelabel2.config(text = Data[index][3])
```